# Function inside directive not being triggered

Tags: angularjs

Why my function toggleCategory function is not being triggered?

Directive

```
app.directive('asideFilter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        toggleCategory: '=&onToggleCategory'
    },
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'assets/directives/asideFilter/asideFilter.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    }
  };
});;
```

Directive template

```
<div ng-click="toggleCategory({id: 'teste'})">TEST</div>
```

Parent scope

```
  $scope.onToggleCategory = function () {
    console.log('onToggleCategory');
  }
```

Parent Caller

```
<aside-filter toggle-category="onToggleCategory({id: 'test '})" categories="categories" />
```

Comment: It's SOLVED! I've just fix the Directive code to: 

scope: { toggleCategory: '=&onToggleCategory' }

Answer (score 1):

You can call the parent controller function like this also

```
app.directive('asideFilter', function() {
 return {
 restrict: 'E',
 scope: {
    toggleCategory: '&',
 },
 transclude: true,
 templateUrl: 'assets/directives/asideFilter/asideFilter.html',
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
 scope.toggleCategoryClick = function (value) {
 scope.toggleCategory(value);
  }
 }
};
});
```

Directive template

```
<div ng-click="toggleCategoryClick({id: 'teste'})">TEST</div>
```

Directive Element

```
<aside-filter toggle-category="onToggleCategory({id: 'test '})" categories="categories" />
```

Comment: Its Great that you figured it out.